# Call quasar from parent webpack

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel and want to include a quasar app into it. Because of this, I have installed the quasar app under `resources/quasar`.

I know, I can just run

```
cd resources/quasar
quasar dev
```

But is there a way to include it into my Laravel / root `webpack.mix.js` file, so that it is called, when building the main project? Otherwise I would have to run multiple build commands.

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json you can add:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack && cd ./resources/quasar && quasar dev",
}
```

And then you'll still have 1 build command.